# Is there a way to remove empty columns of a dataframe and log the header of each removed column?

Tags: r, dna-sequence

I have a dataframe `aSNPst.df` of DNA sequencing information, some points were not read during sequencing

```
|Vol|Sex|Ethnicity|SNP1|SNP2|SNP3|SNP4|SNP5|
|001| M | European| AA | GC |    | TT | GG |
|002| M | European| AA | CC |    | TT | GG |
|003| F | Mixed   | AT | GC |    | AT | GG |
|004| F | European| AA | GC |    | TT | GG |
|005| M | European| TT | GG |    | AT | GG |
```

I think these blank columns mean my code isnt recognising the separator `sep=""`
How do i remove the columns from the dataframe and log which SNP is being removed?

Answer (score 1):

If you have empty values (`""`) in the data you can use :

```
result <- df[colSums(df != '') > 0]
```

If by empty values you actually mean `NA` then do :

```
result <- df[colSums(!is.na(df)) > 0]
```

To get the column names that were removed.

```
removed_columns <- setdiff(names(df), names(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
allna <- sapply(dat, function(z) all(is.na(z)))
allna
#       Vol       Sex Ethnicity      SNP1      SNP2      SNP3      SNP4      SNP5 
#     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE 
which(allna)
# SNP3 
#    6 
names(which(allna))
# [1] "SNP3"

### remove SNP3 from the original data
dat <- dat[,!allna]
```

If you want to look for all `NA` or empty string (`""`), then just adjust the inner function:

```r
allna <- sapply(dat, function(z) all(is.na(z) | !nzchar(z)))
```

---

Data

```r
structure(list(Vol = 1:5, Sex = c("M", "M", "F", "F", "M"), Ethnicity = c("European", "European", "Mixed", "European", "European"), SNP1 = c("AA", "AA", "AT", "AA", "TT"), SNP2 = c("GC", "CC", "GC", "GC", "GG"), SNP4 = c("TT", "TT", "AT", "TT", "AT"), SNP5 = c("GG", "GG", "GG", "GG", "GG")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```